# Python Paramiko send CTRL+C to an ssh shell

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko

I'm invoking a shell using Paramiko in order to use a CLI over an ssh connection. The problem with this CLI is if I do not close it specifically using CTRL+C, the program will not be able to be opened again without rebooting my system.

I've tried the below commands:

```
SSH.send("^C\n")
SSH.send("\x003")
```

is there another way to call these? Again, I've established an SSH connection using `paramiko.SSHClient()` and then invoked a shell using `ssh.invoke_shell()` and now i need to send CTRL+C to that shell to close the shell (not the ssh connection)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're on the right track with your second example, but it isn't quite formatted right. You're actually getting a 2 character string there.

SSH.send("\x03") should do the trick.

However, I'd probably have used this instead.

SSH.send(chr(3))

Comment: That did it my friend thanks for explaining my error here

Comment: How would one send CTRL+A for example would it just be "\x01" instead? if so what encoding scheme is this? Might be worth adding to the answer for completeness? (still upvoted though was very helpful)

Answer (score 3):

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11190794/565212

You can - 

either: pass get_pty=True when calling client.exec_command(). Then client.close() terminates the remote tail.

or: do channel.get_pty() before calling channel.exec_command(). Then channel.close() terminates the remote tail.