# paramiko: automatically terminate remotely started processes

Tags: python, process, paramiko

I want to run a process on a remote machine and I want it to get terminated when my host program exits.

I have a small test script which looks like this:

```
import time
while True:
    print('hello')
    time.sleep(1)
```

and I start this process on a remote machine via a script like this one:

import paramiko

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('my_machine', username='root', key_filename='some_key')
_in, _out, _err = ssh.exec_command('python /home/me/loop.py')
time.sleep(5)  # could do something with in/out/err
ssh.close()
```

But my problem is that the started process keeps running even after I've closed the Python process which started the SSH connection.

Is there a way to force closing the remote session and the remotely started process when the host process gets terminated?

**Edit**:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734679/paramiko-and-exec-command-killing-remote-process) sounds similar but there is no satisfying answer. I tried to set the `keepalive` but with no effect:

```
ssh.get_transport().set_keepalive(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the SSH connection is closed it'll not kill the running command on remote host.

The easiest solution is:

```
ssh.exec_command('python /home/me/loop.py', get_pty=True)
# ... do something ...
ssh.close()
```

Then when the SSH connection is closed, the pty (on remote host) will also be closed and the kernel (on remote host) will send the `SIGHUP` signal to the remote command. By default `SIGHUP` will terminate the process so the remote command will be killed.

---

According to the [APUE](http://www.apuebook.com/) book:

> *SIGHUP* is sent to *the controlling process (session leader)* associated
>   with a *controlling terminal* if a disconnect is detected by the terminal
>   interface.

Comment: This works but only for short running processes. After adding get_pty=True, remote process will be terminated after about 10 minutes. I am looking for solution that allows me to kill remotly running processes and allows the processes to run more than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`closer`](https://haarcuba.github.io/closer/) - a library I've written specifically for this sort of thing. Doesn't use Paramiko, but perhaps it will work for you anyway.