# Paramiko: Asynchronous reading for long shell script output using 'select'

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I have following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14888341/2500806) with little modification:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                  

import paramiko                                                        
import select                                                          


server = "192.168.100.100"                                                
port = 22                                                              
name = "root"                                                          
password = "pass"                                                    


def main():                                                            
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()                                      
    client.load_system_host_keys()                                     

    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.MissingHostKeyPolicy())
    client.connect(server, port, name, password)                       

    channel = client.get_transport().open_session()                    
    channel.exec_command("/tmp/test.sh")                      

    while True:                                                        
        if channel.exit_status_ready():                                
            break                                                      

        r, w, x = select.select([channel], [], [], 0.0)                
        if len(r) > 0:                                                 
            print channel.recv(1024)                                   

if __name__ == "__main__":                                             
    main()
```

Where test.sh has following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true
do
    echo "Message"
    sleep 1
done
```

So after executing python script CPU usage by script goes up to 100%. It means this select function does not wait until one or more file descriptors are ready for some kind of I/O. As far as knew this is busy loop problem where 'while ... loop' will iterate continuously even data for read is not presented. How I can make it asynchronous read of remote output?

Comment: What do you want to happen while `select` is doing it's thing? You have code dependent on the output immediately after.

Comment: For instance if sleep time in bash script is equal to 5. Select.select should wait until output will be generated instead of looping without any sleep. Maybe I misunderstood of meaning 'select'. What I want to do is read generated output asynchronously.

Comment: You're using the word 'asynchronously' but based on your explanation, I don't think that's what you want. It sounds like you're saying you **want** `select` to block until it gets a result. You just don't want to have it loop endlessly, but instead wait without maxing out CPU. Is that right?

Comment: @Eli yes this is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you have timeout set to 0 seconds on select, so it doesn't block at all. The default is to block as long as necessary, so either take out the timeout parameter from `select`, or change it to something larger:

```
r, w, x = select.select([channel], [], [])
```

or

```
r, w, x = select.select([channel], [], [], 10.0)
```

You can see the difference both in CPU, and also by putting a simple print statement after your `while true`. In the 0.0 second timeout statement, you'll see it hit continuously. In the greater timeout case you'll see it hit exactly once (and cpu much lower).