# Paramiko finish process before reading all output

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm Trying to make a real time SSH Library, but as usually getting stuck on things, I have taken this code from [Long-running ssh commands in python paramiko module (and how to end them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760978/long-running-ssh-commands-in-python-paramiko-module-and-how-to-end-them).
But this code doesn't prints the whole output.

I guess that when the while loop exits on channel.exit_status_ready() the channel still have data to read. I've been trying to fix this but the fix was not on all inputs.

How can I make this work to print all kind of commands?

```
import paramiko
import select

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect('host.example.com')
channel = client.get_transport().open_session()
channel.exec_command("cd / && ./test.sh")
while True:
    if channel.exit_status_ready():
        break
    rl, wl, xl = select.select([channel], [], [], 0.0)
    if len(rl) > 0:
        print channel.recv(1024)
```

test.sh:

```
echo 1
wait 1
echo 2
wait 1
echo 3
```

Output:

```
1

2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce problem with your command, but I can reproduce it with command like `cat some_big_file.txt`.

So looks like you are right in your hypothesis. Exit status can be ready before you read all the stuff from your `channel`. It's not clear if you really need to use `select`. If not I would rewrite loop:

```
while True:
    buf = channel.recv(1024)
    if not buf:
        break
    print buf
```

Such loop will keep reading the channel while it has some data in it. If you really want to use `select` you can put the above loop just after your loop. It will read and print remaining data.

Comment: I have some similar issue and your code helped but if try to send more than one command, the loop does not break. Looks like the `if not buf: break` portion is not working. I can't find anything on the internet on how to compare bytes in the buffer. Any thoughts?