# pexpect multithread program hangs when spawning a shell

Tags: python, multithreading, fork, pexpect

I have a multi-threaded program. When the program is running, some of the threads hang sometimes during the call to pexpect.spawn().

This program creates a Session object in each thread, and a Session object spawns a pexpect session when it is created. In the program, each Session object is binding to one specific thread.

```
class CustomizedThread(threading.Thread):
    __init__(self, thread_name):
        super().__init__(name=thread_name)

    def run(self):
        session = Session()
        ...

class Session:
    __init__(self, session_name):
        self.name = session_name
        print('Thread {} is spawning a shell in session {}.'.format(
            threading.currentThread(), session.name))
        self.pexpect_session = pexpect.spawn('/bin/sh')
        print('Thread {} finished spawning a shell in session {}.'.format(
            threading.currentThread(), session.name))
        self.pexpect_session.sendline('ssh MACHINE_NAME')
        ...

    __del__(self):
        print('Thread {} is cleaning up session {}.'.format(
            threading.currentThread(), session.name))
        self.pexepect_session.close(force=True)
```

The following is an example output when thread 2 is hanging, the destructor of Session object 1 is triggered during the call to pexpect.spawn() on thread 2.

```
...
Thread 1 is spawning a shell in session 1.
Thread 1 finished spawning a shell in session 1.
Thread 2 is spawning a shell in session 2.
Thread 2 is cleaning up session 1.
```

Attaching the hanging process to gdb, and I got the following stack trace. It shows the thread is hanging when attempting to write the exception message to a file descriptor:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007fff9628391a in write () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
#1  0x000000010ed7aa22 in _Py_write_impl (fd=2, buf=0x10f3f1010, count=76, gil_held=1) at ../Python/fileutils.c:1269
#2  0x000000010ed7a9a1 in _Py_write (fd=2, buf=0x10f3f1010, count=76) at ../Python/fileutils.c:1327
#3  0x000000010ede8795 in _io_FileIO_write_impl (self=0x10f3875f8, b=0x7000013dd168) at ../Modules/_io/fileio.c:840
#4  0x000000010ede7957 in _io_FileIO_write (self=0x10f3875f8, arg=0x11312c148)
at ../Modules/_io/clinic/fileio.c.h:245
#5  0x000000010ebbfd72 in PyCFunction_Call (func=0x112ed7b98, args=0x112fc6330, kwds=0x0)
at ../Objects/methodobject.c:134
#6  0x000000010eb2803d in PyObject_Call (func=0x112ed7b98, arg=0x112fc6330, kw=0x0) at ../Objects/abstract.c:2165
#7  0x000000010eb290de in PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs (callable=0x112ed7b98, name=0x10f234d40)
at ../Objects/abstract.c:2394
#8  0x000000010edf0456 in _bufferedwriter_raw_write (self=0x10f25de58,
start=0x10f3f1010 "\nThread 2 is cleaning up session 1. \"terminated\" is 0, but there was no child process. Did someone else call waitpid() on our process?\n"...,
len=76) at ../Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:1847
```

The exception message '"terminated" is 0, but there was no child process. Did someone else call waitpid() on our process?' is from the line where the pexpect session is closed

```
self.pexepect_session.close(force=True)
```

Also, in the spawn() method of pexpect, the process is forked (the process that I attached to in gdb) to execute '/bin/sh' and a pipe is created to write any exception message to the parent process.

It looks like the forked process garbage collected the Session object of another thread but caught a exception when trying to close a session on another thread. The process is hanging writing the exception message to the pipe because the exception message should've been read from the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using threads to spawn shells and pexpect to run ssh, just use [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/).  It's a very good, mature library which implements ssh without having to shell out.  And you can run multiple sessions in a single thread which will probably be more efficient in Python anyway--see here: [Long-running ssh commands in python paramiko module (and how to end them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760978/long-running-ssh-commands-in-python-paramiko-module-and-how-to-end-them)

Comment: Thank you! The program needs more than SSH. It is also used to telnet to some embedded boards, and Paramiko does not support that.

Comment: @Tsu-Hao: then how about https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be worked around by switching to multiprocessing. Mixing multithreading and fork is problematic.