# Long-running commands block in paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I want to run an auto deployment of some software on a remote server. Anyway, the output of the remote command always blocks and never ends. I have checked the remote server and I can confirm that the command is still running, though the stdout printed by paramiko blocks.

I have read the solution from this post: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760978/long-running-ssh-commands-in-python-paramiko-module-and-how-to-end-them/766255#766255)

```
import paramiko
import select

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect('host.example.com')
channel = client.get_transport().open_session()
channel.exec_command("packstack --allinone")
while True:
    if channel.exit_status_ready():
        break
    rl, wl, xl = select.select([channel], [], [], 0.0)
    if len(rl) > 0:
        print channel.recv(1024)
```

Each time when I use `Ctrl + C` to force the script stop, it seems to be stuck at `rl, wl, xl = select.select([channel], [], [], 0.0)`.

For reference, I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504126/do-you-have-to-check-exit-status-ready-if-you-are-going-to-check-recv-ready) post  .But no luck found.

How can I modify the code to make it work with the long-lasting and large-outputting command?

Now I found the problem.
Actually it was not stuck at `rl, wl, xl = select.select([channel], [], [], 0.0)`. Since the `timeout` was set to `0.0`, it was in a non-blocking pattern.

Therefore, the problem is that, the program executed the `while` loop forever but it just could not receive anything from the `channel`, although the remote process was still outputting stuff.

I assume this could be caused by either paramiko or a bad remote server.

Now my solution is to rerun my command when the channel could not receive anything in a limited time, say 120 seconds, while exit signal not received.

Comment: Try `exec_command("for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo $i; sleep 1; done")` and see if it works for you.

Comment: @whjm I tried. The output is correct and it never hangs.

Answer (score 0):

It use to happen when there is no data in stdout or there is a line without eol (i.e. in a read statement inside a sh script). Try setting 'get_pty=True', then reading only the bytes in stdout. Here is an example using exec_command directly with the SSHClient.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
...
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("your-command",get_pty=True)
stdout.flush()
nbytes = 0
while (len(stdout.channel.in_buffer)==0):
     continue

nbytes=len(stdout.channel.in_buffer)
print(nbytes)
stdout.read(nbytes)
```