# How to exit python subprocess if it fails

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am reading some output of remote server using SSH bash(`command`). I need to do it constantly, so I spawn subprocess. It works fine, unless server server become unavailable for brief period.
How do I restart SSH command (whole subprocess) if it fails?

I have following piece of code:

```
(...)

process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
while True:
    line = process.stdout.readline()
    if lines == "" and process.poll() is not None:
        break
(...)
```

I would think that `process.poll() is not None` should do the trick
but it seems to hang on

```
1000     21431  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Z+   Oct22   0:00 [ssh] <defunct>
```

And does not break out of `while True:`

Comment: Just put the entire block into another ``while True`` as well?

Comment: the problem is that the ssh process inside goes to `[ssh] <defunct>
` state and process.stdout.readline() waits forever. I would like to break out of readline() when ssh disconnects...

Comment: might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760978/long-running-ssh-commands-in-python-paramiko-module-and-how-to-end-them

Comment: I had bug in my code afterall... silly typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had silly typo error in my code preventing `if lines == "" and process.poll() is not None:` from executing properly.
Another thing to look at is ssh_config, It is wise to set values to disconnect @60 seconds/1 attempt.
And avoid process.communicate() as it is blocking the whole thread.